# What condition is this checking for: if [ -z $1 ]

Tags: linux, bash, macos, shell, unix

I have three if conditions in a shell script I have been given, can I be assisted with what they each mean in English. Also, how would I use the man pages to find out similar commands in the future?

The conditions are as follows:

1. `if [ -z $1 ]`
2. `if [ ! -r $1 ]`
3. `if [ -n $3 ]`

Comment: Just checked, everything is in `bash(1)`, see https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash

Comment: Every command listed in this question is buggy, btw. Needs to be quoted as in `[ -z "$1" ]` to actually behave the way you expect it to. Otherwise, with an empty string, instead of being `[ -z "" ]`, it becomes `[ -n "-z" ]` (because `-n` is the default test in the single-argument case) -- it's still true, but it's true for a different reason than what you expect and intend; and there are other, odder corner cases when the quoting is missing as well.

Comment: ...similarly, `[ -n $3 ]` becomes `[ -n ]`, which is treated as `[ -n "-n" ]`, when `$3` is empty; *unless* you quote it as `[ -n "$3" ]`, in which case it actually does the right thing.

Comment: @gst what section in bash(1), I didn't see it in options and document is very long?

Comment: @thecartesianman did you try searching on the website? See Conditional Expressions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick here is that `[` is not punctuation, but the name of a command, which is also called `test`. So the help page you need is `man test`.

On that page, you can see the options listed:

```
   -z STRING
          the length of STRING is zero

   ! EXPRESSION
          EXPRESSION is false

   -r FILE
          FILE exists and read permission is granted

   -n STRING
          the length of STRING is nonzero
```

Since bash includes a built-in implementation of this command, you can also find the information under `man bash` and in [the bash reference manual](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Builtin-Commands).

Comment: yeah, just lookup `help [` — intuitive, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

See "CONDITIONAL EXPRESSIONS" in `man bash`:

> ```
> -r file
>           True if file exists and is readable.
>
> -n string
>           True if the length of string is non-zero.   
>
> -z string
>           True if the length of string is zero.
> ```

Interestingly, `!` is not documented in the context of `[ ... ]`, but it means negation in the same way as in other contexts. You can find the explanation in `help test` or in `man bash` under SHELL BUILTIN COMMANDS, section `[ expr ]`.